# How to pass html full data through JSON text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a jquery code where I am trying to get a whole html page as json text.

now this code I want to write in json string.

in json

text1 will contain the full html in single string format which will be passed to jquery.

can it be done please tell me how to incorporate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this possible using jQuery, but you could try this:

```
var text1 = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Please be aware, as Firefox 10 and below doesn't support `outerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("html").html();` to get the entire page html. You can then put it in text1:

```
var text1 = $("html").html();
```

Comment: That won't include the `html` element itself (or any attributes on it).

Answer (score 0):

Since ur jquery code will give you whole html page as json text. so you can use JSON.stringify(object) to write in json string. Look at below sample.

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.name = "Raj";
obj.age  = 32;
obj.married = false;
var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
```

like if it satisfies you.

Comment: Thank you but this was not what I asked for anyways I found the way to do it , thankx anyways for the help